# PHP - mb_convert_encoding() does not convert accents to utf8 correctly

Tags: php, string, encoding, utf-8

For my customer I need to convert ANSI(Windows) files with accents

I try to convert the data to utf8, to be later parsed by regex (validation) the imported in db

example : "idées" (french word for ideas)

- if I force the UTF8 in notepad++ , it works

  ```
   the data displays as : id├®es
  ```
- if I use the original ANSI file and use PHP to convert the data , it does not work

  ```
   $_value=mb_convert_encoding($value, "Windows-1252","UTF-8");

   the data displays as : idÚes
  ```

please help

thanks

Comment: And what is the coding of the page on which you are displaying the result in php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the arguments the wrong way around.

From http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php:

> `string mb_convert_encoding ( string $str , string $to_encoding [, mixed $from_encoding = mb_internal_encoding() ] )`

So you need

```
$_value=mb_convert_encoding($value, "UTF-8", "Windows-1252");
```

Also check whether you need to convert with [mb_check_encoding](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-check-encoding.php), just in case you happen to read a file that's already UTF-8

Comment: thanks, I found it weird to have question marks someimes, now it works :-)